# Laravel migration "Identifier name is too long"

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'gjsdjuejwpls_personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index' is too long (SQL: alter table gjsdjuejwpls_personal_access_tokens add index gjsdjue jwpls_personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index(tokenable_type, tokenable_id))

**Please tell me how to fix this error. Vedas this migration at once at installation costs.**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->morphs('tokenable');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
        $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: `Table 'gjsdjuejwpls_personal_access_tokens' already exists` means that you've already created this table

Comment: When creating writes: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1059 Identifier name 'gjsdjuejwpls_personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index' is too long (SQL: alter table `gjsdjuejwpls_personal_access_tokens` add index `gjsdjue
jwpls_personal_access_tokens_tokenable_type_tokenable_id_index`(`tokenable_type`, `tokenable_id`))         [![2022-05-28-205243480.png](https://i.postimg.cc/tCZFBYcQ/2022-05-28-205243480.png)](https://postimg.cc/svzBXDyw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a shorter index name as second argument to the `morphs()` in the migration

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        // Provide shorter index name as the second argument
        $table->morphs('tokenable', 'personal_access_tokenable_index');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
        $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

MySQL has a limit of 64 characters for the length of index names - (refer the link posted by Bill Karwin in comment below). By default Laravel uses table_name_column(s)_name(s)_index as the format for identifier (index names). So if it exceeds the limit of 64 characters then it will throw an error

Comment: Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html

Comment: Thank you all understood!